# How do you save 4 bytes/ints to a short?

Tags: c

I am reading a file and just read 4 bytes (the size of a short) and have them saved into a `int[4]`. How do I make these 4 bytes, a short?

Comment: How can you be sure that a `short` can even hold four bytes?  On many platforms, it won't.

Comment: Just fread()into your int.

Comment: @user83039 Question is not making much sense, 1st of all short will hardly be of 4 bytes, then you are saying saving them in `int[4]` an array of 4 integers, which means you are saving each byte in different int, occupying total of 16 bytes, considering int needs 4 bytes., didn't get anything....

Comment: I haven't seen any platforms where a `short` is not 16 bits (2 bytes).

Comment: I wonder if endianness is a missing part of the question..

Comment: Post the result of `printf("%u\n", (unsigned) sizeof (short));`.

Comment: I ended up doing what @JonathonReinhart suggested and used `fread(..., sizeof(short), ..., ...) and saving it as a short.

Answer (score -1):

Use sizeof operator to take sizes (to check) and cast them.

```
int number;
short x = (short) number;
```

Remember to see your SHRT_MAX (limits.h) to make casting or you will lose and corrupt data.